# Postgres - Left Join, same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of subscription records for people subscribed to groups. There's a groupid column and a userid column (in addition to the primary key id). I want to find all the subscription rows of people subscribed to group 1 that do not also have a subscription record for group 2. I thought I could use an anti-join pattern, but I can't get it to work. I've tried:

```
SELECT
*
FROM subs s1
LEFT JOIN subs s2 ON s1.groupid=1 AND s2.groupid=2 AND s1.userid=s2.userid
WHERE s2.id IS NULL;
```

But that does not work (it returns subscription records with groupids that are not 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `group by` for this:

```
select s.userid
from subs s
group by s.userid
having sum(case when s.groupid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when s.groupid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts records for one of the groups.  The first condition says there is at least one row with `groupid = 1`.  The second says there are no records with `groupid = 2`.

You *can* do what you want with a `left join` as well.  Here is the approach:

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM subs s1 LEFT JOIN
     subs s2
     ON s1.userid = s2.userid AND s2.groupid = 2
WHERE  s1.groupid = 1 AND s2.id IS NULL;
```

Because it is a `left join`, the condition on the first table should go in the `where` clause.